# Isomorphism between $H_1(X)$ and $\pi_1(X)^{ab}$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups

I'd like to understand the proof of the following theorem, born from the conciseness of the proof given. It's also called Hurewicz's theorem in the special case $n=1$. The essential doubts about the proof, which doesn't go in detail about, are :

$\textbf{1}.$ Is $l'$ well defined ? It seems to me that the $u(x)$ is a generic path, which I think is not what we want since doesn't give the property $lh = id$. For example given a loop $\sigma = h([\gamma])$ with basis in $x_0$, we could consider instead of $u(x_0) = c_{x_{0}}$ the costant loop in $x_0$, a random loop so that we have a "$3$-loop" which doesn't return in $[\gamma]$ with $l'$.

$\textbf{2}.$ I don't how $\triangle^2$ being contractible implies that $\tau_2 \star \tau_1 \sim \tau_1$. I think I can prove the statement using that the simplex is convex but I don't see how the contractbile property of the space implies such homotopy

$\textbf{3}.$ I think the question three is linked to question one, I'd like to understand why the last equality holds : $[\sigma] = [u(\sigma_0)]+[\sigma] - [u(\sigma_1)] =  [(u(\sigma_0)\star \sigma)\star u(\sigma_1)^-]$

I'm currently reading the proof on Algebraic Topology of Tammo Tom Dieck, I add below a picture of the proof of the theorem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1, $l'$ is well-defined because $C_1(X)$ is a free abelian group generated by the 1-simplices of $X$, so you get a well-defined map from $C_1(X)$ to any other abelian group by specifying where the generators go. If you have a loop based at $x_0$, then the key is that you have to use the same path $u$ from $x_0$ to $x_0$ at both ends in the definition of $l'$, traveling along $u$ once in each direction, so $l h$ will indeed be the identity map.

For question 2, the statement is accurate, but maybe to make it easier, the author should have said that $\Delta^2$ strongly deformation retracts to any of its vertices (for example because of convexity). But see [Path homotopy in contractible space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3602137/path-homotopy-in-contractible-space) if you just want to use contractibility.

For question 3, it is not the case that $[\sigma] = \dots$. Rather, the extra terms $\sum a_{\sigma}([u(\sigma_0)] - [u(\sigma_1)])$ taken together give precisely the boundary of $\sum a_{\sigma} \sigma$ and therefore add up to zero, since the original sum is assumed to be a cycle. For the last equality, $u(\sigma_0) + \sigma - u(\sigma_1)$ should be homologous to $(u(\sigma_0)*\sigma)*u(\sigma_1)^{-}$, so the sums are equal when working in $H_1$.

Comment: As far as concern question 1, if you use one loop different from $h([\gamma])$ it doesn't seems to me that $lh$ is not the identity, should I be using $h([\gamma])$ itself ?

Comment: If $\gamma$ is a loop based at $x_0$ and you choose $u(x_0)$ to be another loop based at $x_0$ for the purposes of defining $l'$, then $l' h([\gamma])$ will be a loop that first follows $u(x_0)$, then $\gamma$, then the reverse of $u(x_0)$. Since this is happening in the abelianization of $\pi_1$, the result is equal to $[\gamma]$.

Comment: I could choose a different path not the inverse of $u(x_0)$ as third path, couldn't it ?

Comment: What if the first path $u_1(x_0)$ bounds a hole and $u_2(x_0)$ does not, this homotopy class doesn't seems to the same as $[\gamma]$.

Comment: It's the same path — $u_1 = u_2$. From the proof: "For each $x \in X$ we choose a path $u(x)$ from $x_0$ to $x$." So you cannot use two different paths from $x_0$ to $x_0$, you have to use the same one every time it arises. (First you choose a path $u(x)$ for each $x$, and then you use this to define the function $l'$.)

Comment: Actually says "for $x \in X$ we define", which seems to indicate that the procedure is defined every time, but I think I got this point, thanks.

Comment: But choosing a different path from $x_0$ to $\sigma_0$ for example leads to the same image ?

Comment: You have to make the choice first, choosing a path for each $x \in X$, and that defines the function $l'$. Maybe a different choice of paths could lead to different $l'$, I'm not sure and I'm not interested in thinking about it, but the induced map $l$ will be the same (since among other things it is an inverse to $h$).

Comment: This types of comments are really not costructive for the purpose of the site, thanks anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120862/discussion-between-john-palmieri-and-jacopoburelli).

Comment: Regarding the last point, any two choices for $l'$ induce the same map $l$, so they must agree.